# How to open exported .exe Jar file or RUN.bat file in different computer?

Tags: java, jar, export, executable

I recently made a game and trying to distribute to my friends.

I exported .exe Jar file in Eclipse, and tried to open it to see if it works, but somehow it didn't so I had to manually make RUN.bat file, and it worked. So I zipped those two files together and send it to my friends. But they all said the neither file does not work.

The error message is this :
"It is not an internal or external command, executable program, or batch file."

So it worked in my computer and it didn't work when it was in other computers.
How could I resolve the problem? Is it because they didn't have Eclipse? Is there any way they can run without having Eclipse or anything?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "It is not an internal or external command, executable program, or batch file."

Answer (score 2):

Your batch problably is using java -jar in your .bat, and your friends does not have JRE installed

Comment: So JRE must to be installed to run java -jar, right..?

Comment: Yes, it must be installed

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer.
I should add JRE install file with my game file and then distribute!